# How to pass textbox and dropdown value from view to controller in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, model-view-controller, razor

I would like to know how to pass values from a textbox and selected value  to a controller. At the moment I am able to get to my controller but the value of what was entered in textbox and value of what was selected in dropdown is always null by the time it reaches the controller and I am not sure why.Perhaps I should be doing this using the ViewData instead?

**my textbox, dropdown and search button**

```
<div id="cc" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Advanced Search</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AdvancedFilteredSearch", "FilteredSearch", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "frmAdvancedSearch", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <br />
                    <select class="form-control" id="condition" name="condition">
                        <option value="">Select Search Conditions</option>
                        <option value="1">Between</option>
                        <option value="2">Or</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


               <div>
                <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control validate" placeholder="Type here">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Clear Filters</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("FilteredSearch", "FilteredSearch")'"class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



**My Controller Method**




  public ActionResult AdvancedFilteredSearch(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string value = Convert.ToString(collection["search"]);
        string value = Convert.ToString(collection["condition"]);
        return View(db.marketingdbclients_dataTable.Where(a => a.ClientId < 500));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used FormCollection class before. But as far as i rememeber, when you submit your form you can simply do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdvancedFilteredSearch(int condition, string search )
    {
        return View(db.marketingdbclients_dataTable.Where(a => a.ClientId < 500));
    }
```

Your variables "condition" and "search" should be the same with id of your HTML form-element. And don't forget about HttpPost attribute before your method.

Comment: Also you can create another object with variables inside:
`class FormFilter{ string condition {get;set;} string search {get;set;} } `

And then use this object as parameter: 
`public ActionResult AdvancedFilteredSearch(FormFilter filter)`
After that you can get value of elements in this way: `filter.condition`